# Is it possible to have a full house and straight flush in same hand with only two players?

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

In Texas Holdem, Is it possible to have a full house and straight flush in same hand with only two players?

Comment: The number of players is irrelevant, unless you're playing by yourself.

Comment: Why would number of players matter, each player has 2 cards added to the 5 community cards. The only way number of players could matter is if there were more community cards based on number of players, or you were asking to make more combinations than the number of players (one player with a straight flush and full house)

Answer (score 15):

Certainly.

Player 1 : 5♥ 6♥

Player 2 : 8♣ 9♣

Community cards: 7♥ 8♥ 9♥ 8♦ 9♦

Player one has 5♥ 6♥ 7♥ 8♥ 9♥

Player two has 8♣ 8♥ 9♣ 9♥ 9♦

Comment: You can also have Royal Flush and Quad Aces...  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XunAlp2azhA

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I've done it for real at the casino. Made a big score!

- The final straight flush: **K,Q,J,T,9**, all one suit.
- I had an Ace Ten off, the Ten made the straight flush.
- Another player held pocket pair of Kings to make a **K,K,K,J,J** full house.

Board ends up **K,J,J,Q,9** where 4 cards matched the suit of my 10.